# Generic CXF server implementation

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I'm currently working on a project using Spring Boot as well as CXF.
I have successfully created a SOAP-client as well as a SOAP-server for a specific webservice (with a related WSDL). Works like a charm.

Now I need to implement some kind of proxy server, which just interprets the SOAP-Header (Security, Custom Headers) and routes the SOAP-Service to a different backend depending on the content of the custom headers.

But I haven't found an option to handle a service call generically. All online solutions suggest me to have all the WSDLs of the different proxied services in the proxy and to generate an internal cxf-model.

Is there a way to accomplish this without WSDL / internal model? Haven't found a solution yet.

One approach I followed was to implement a custom CXF Implementor and bind it to an endpoint.

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint()
{
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), customImplementor);
        endpoint.publish("/proxy");

        return endpoint;
}
```

But there isn't an implementor interface I can extend.

Do I miss smth here?
What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like if you need handlers...
Just define an interceptor class and them do something like this.

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint()
{
    InterceptorClass handler = context.getBean(InterceptorClass.class);
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), customImplementor);
    endpoint.setHandlers(Arrays.asList(handler));
    endpoint.publish("/proxy");

    return endpoint;
}
```

Check an example here [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html) of how create an interceptor class.

Comment: Hi winter, thanks for your answer.
Yes the interceptor approach is right to interpret the headers. We already are capable of handling them.

The problem is how to handle the service since a wsdl is needed. The proxy should be able to process the service request without wsdl or internal service model (just ignore the request body)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use cxf-camel and create proxy service, it has ability to route based on the your requirement that is header param based. [Here](https://github.com/kprasad99/spring-boot-cxf-jaxws-camel-proxy) is basic example implementation of the proxy service using spring-boot-cxf and spring-boot-camel